# nodejs res.json display in html

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

trying to display data queried from mongo db via nodejs to html index.html. 
What the script does? it open the server connection , connect to mongodb and from the webform with datapicker it display the result query, via console i can see the result and it is working perfectly, now i need to display the data to web.

So far no result. Any suggestion?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = __dirname + '/views/';
var fs = require("fs");


const util = require('util')

//lets require/import the mongodb native drivers.
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

//We need to work with "MongoClient" interface in order to connect to a mongodb server.
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/klevin';


router.use(function (req,res,next) {
    console.log("/" + req.method);
    next();
});



router.get("/",function(req,res){

    res.sendFile(path + "index.html");



    var data_e_fillimit = req.param('start_time');
    //console.log(params.startDate)
    console.log('Data e fillimit '+data_e_fillimit)


    var data_e_mbarimit= req.param('endtime_time');
    //console.log(params.startDate)
    console.log('Data e mbarimit '+data_e_mbarimit)


// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
    console.log('Connection established to', url);


    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('frames');

    //We have a cursor now with our find criteria
    var cursor = collection.find({
      tv: 'tematv', 
      date_created: {"$gte": new Date(data_e_fillimit) , "$lte": new Date(data_e_mbarimit) }});

    //We need to sort by age descending
    cursor.sort({_id: -1});

    //Limit to max 10 records
    cursor.limit(50);

    //Skip specified records. 0 for skipping 0 records.
    cursor.skip(0);


    //Lets iterate on the result
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {

      if (err) {

        console.log(err);
        //res.json(err);

      } else {

        console.log('Fetched:', doc);
       // res.json({ user: 'tobi' })



      }
    });


  }



});



});


/*router.get("/about",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path + "about.html");
});


router.get("/contact",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path + "contact.html");
});*/

app.use("/",router);

/*app.use("*",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path + "404.html");
});*/

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Live at Port 3000");
});
```

Comment: use angularjs to consume api's in view,., it is simple

Answer (score 0):

use `ejs` (`npm install ejs --save`) package try like this:

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);    
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.render('index.html',{
      foo:bar
    });
});
```

now use can use this object that passed to the index.html